# AWS Gateway, CloudFront, and Lambda Edge - Logging request and response payloads?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I created a CloudFront with Gateway as the origin and I'm using a lambda edge function with origin response event trigger behaviour to Cloundfront to log the request and response but I'm only able to log the request headers and response headers and status code. Is there a way to access response body and request payload within the lambda function and use it aswell?

I tried accessing the response and request body but it is coming as undefined